# React change DOM every X seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render some cards with different content every 10 seconds, I first fetch the data from the API and then render the first set of data on cards and what I want to do is change the cards content every 10 seconds

For the moment I'm using this:

```
    const [cards, setCards] = useState<[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {

     props.data.map( (data: any, i: any) => 

          setTimeout(() => {
            setCards(data)
          }, i * 10000)
     )

    }, [cards])

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <Hero img={bg} />
            <Cards cards={cards} />
        </Wrapper>
    )
```

That's currently not working, what can I do to make it work correctly ?
My final result is every 10 seconds change the content (I will implement some animations too)

Comment: You can call the setTimeout recursively to fetch the data or you can even use setInterval for that which will fetch the data. Just remember to unmount it as soon as the component is unmounted using a return statement

Comment: @innocent I'm fetching the data server-side with `getServerSideProps`...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

I just removed `cards` from my `useEffect` hook and used an empty array instead..
Working fine.